# How do I fire a bullet in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

My objective is to make a space invaders type of game, where the spaceship can move up, down, left and right, and fire bullets at the alien.

I've yet to make the collision part of the code as I am stuck at the firing bullets part.

I've assigned spacebar to fire bullets yet I'm unable to see any bullet firing.
Please help me out.

```
import pygame
import random

# for initialising pygame (req for every pygame app)
pygame.init()

# making the basic window (dimensions must be written inside a tuple )
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

# background
background = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/aryan/Downloads/background.jpg')

# load and set the logo
logo = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/aryan/Downloads/bp.png')  # directory of logo
pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
pygame.display.set_caption("space wars")  # program name

# define a variable to control the main loop
running = True

# player
playerimg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/aryan/Downloads/spaceship.png')
playerX = 218  # x and y coordinates of image
playerY = 350
playerxchange = 0  # this will be the change in movement in x direction of our image
playerychange = 0  # this will be the change in movement in y direction of our image


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))  # blit draws our image on the surface(basically the background)
    # syntax for blit(imagename, (xcoordinate,ycoordinate))


# enemy
enemyimg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/aryan/Downloads/enemy.png')
enemyX = random.randint(0, 476)
enemyY = 20
enemyxchange = 0.2
enemyychange = 40

# game over
overimg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/aryan/Downloads/gameover.png')

# bullet
bulletimg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/aryan/Downloads/bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 350
bulletxchange = 0
bulletychange = 7
bullet_state = "ready"              # "ready" you cant see bullet on screen
                                    # "fire" you can see bullet firing

def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemyimg, (x, y))  # blit draws our image on the surface(basically the background)
    # syntax for blit(imagename, (xcoordinate,ycoordinate))


def firebullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "ready"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x+12, y+6))


# main loop
while running:
    screen.fill((120, 120, 120))  # in order (r, g, b) . (0, 0, 0) is black (255, 0, 0) is red...
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    # event handling, gets all event from the event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # only do something if the event is of type QUIT
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # change the value to False, to exit the main loop
            running = False

        # checking keystroke
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerxchange += 0.2  # change in movement will be 0.2 towards the right
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerxchange -= 0.2  # change in movement will be 0.2 towards the right
            #if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            #    playerychange -= 0.2
            #if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            #   playerychange += 0.2
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullet_state = "fire"
                firebullet(playerX, bulletY)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerxchange = 0
                playerychange = 0

    playerY += playerychange
    playerX += playerxchange  # the value of playerx changes by +- 0.1 depending on keystroke

    if playerX <= -64:  # this teleports the spaceship from left end to right end
        playerX = 564
    elif playerX >= 564:  # this teleports spaceship from right end to left
        playerX = -64

    if playerY >= 436:  # this prevents spaceship from leaving vertically
        playerY = 436
    if playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0

    # enemy movement
    enemyX += enemyxchange

    if enemyY >= 476:
        enemyY = 476
        enemyYchange = 0
        enemyXchange = 0

    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyxchange = 0.1
        enemyY += enemyychange
    elif enemyX >= 465:
        enemyxchange = -0.1
        enemyY += enemyychange

    # bullet movement
    if bullet_state is "fire":
        firebullet(playerX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletychange

    player(playerX, playerY)  # player method is called AFTER screen.fill otherwise the screen will fill after image has been blitted
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)

    pygame.display.update()  # necessary for events to keep updating
```

Also, the comments may seem trivial, but I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the bullet firing because you only call `screen.blit(bulletimg, (x+12, y+6))` once in your `firebullet` function. After this, a new loop begins and the background gets printed over it with `screen.blit(background, (0, 0))`, and no code is called to render your bullet anymore. What you need is to keep each bullet in memory and call `.blit()` every loop iteration so that they're all printed correctly.

Here's a basic solution:

```
...
bullets = [] #Array to store the position of the bullets
...

def firebullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "ready"
    bullets.append([x + 12, y + 6]) # Creating a new bullet

...

while running:
    ...

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        firebullet(playerX, bulletY)
        # bulletY -= bulletychange # No longer necessary, we'll do this right afterwards

    for bullet in bullets:
        screen.blit(bulletimg, (bullet[0], bullet[1])) # Print a bullet
        bullet[0] -= bulletxchange # Updates its position
        bullet[1] -= bulletychange
        if bullet[1] < 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet) # If the bullet goes offscreen, delete it from the array
```

Comment: "and no code is called to render your bullet anymore. What you need is to keep each bullet in memory and call .blit() every loop iteration so that they're all printed correctly", could you please explain this to me in a somewhat easier to comprehend way? Sorry for the trouble, I only just began pygame.

Comment: @Dudeness Sure, I'll try. Every loop, you print the background to clear the previous screen, and print the enemies and the player afterwards. Try not printing the background nor calling `screen.fill()`, and you'll see that moving entities would leave a trail made of their previous positions if you didn't do this. This means that unless you print something every loop after the background, it simply will be printed once, then the background will be printed above it and so it won't be visible anymore. That's why you need to remember the bullets' positions and print them every loop iteration.

Comment: thanks, also can you explain the last few lines of code that you've written?
"for bullet in ....
bullets.remove(bullet)"

Comment: @Dudeness `bullets` is a list that contains the coordinates of every bullet. I iterate through it using `for bullet in bullets:`, to access each bullet individually : after this, I left a bunch of comments to explain why I wrote what I wrote. What may be unclear is that the way I wrote it, `bullet[0]` is its X coordinate, and `bullet[1]` its Y coordinate.